# Dialog stays open with the loader and it never closes

Tags: content-hub, taxonomy

I have a form for creating new taxonomy values for a specific taxonomy. I have the same form and the same configuration for more than 1 taxonomy. Some of them work correctly: I fill the fields of the dialog form, press add and it is created. But others, when I press add, the dialog stays open with the loader and it never closes.

[image: theme popup]

When I press add, the dialog stays open with the loader and it never closes.
Can somebody help?

Comment: What does your browser console say? Any errors / warnings?